# Search work item history

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, bug-reporting

Is there a way in Team Foundation Server to search in the work item history? For example, using the query editor you can add the expression "AssignedTo=PersonName" which fetches all tickets assigned to that person. But how would you setup a query so that it fetches all tickets that has ever been assigned to that person, even if the current assignee is someone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Was Ever` operator in your query:

[image: Was Ever]